# jekyll error / sh: command not found: jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I installed jekyll and when i run this command

```
jekyll serve --watch
```

I get

```
sh: command not found: jekyll
```

This is what's inside my zshrc file

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
```

and ruby -v

```
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
```

I run OSX 10.9

I found some solutions that suggest to change the PATH but not working.

Not experienced with ruby.

Thanks

Edit:

```
gem environment

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/user1/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Changed the path to

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
```

but still not working

Comment: What directory is jekyll installed in? Is it in your $PATH?

Comment: Try using `hash -r` to update your shell's hash table.

Comment: @Barmar I updated my question with info about gem

Comment: My question remains: is jekyl installed in any of those directories?

Comment: Why do you have `$HOME` before `/usr`?

Comment: @Barmar jekylle installed  in /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0

Comment: You didn't add that directory to your PATH, you added `$HOME/usr/local/...`.

Comment: I would suggest at this point you run `brew doctor` as it looks as though it did not set things up correctly.

Comment: @tamouse I run brew doctor and get a lot of warnings  https://gist.github.com/ahmadajmi/7223439 and trying to solve them . I think all the problems happens after upgrading to osx 10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after @tamouse suggested to run brew doctor I got theses [warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699323/brew-warnings-when-running-brew-doctor?noredirect=1#comment29261655_19699323) and I managed to fix them and I think this was the main issue after upgrading to OSX 10.9.

After that I installed Ruby using

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

and this fixed the issue.

Thanks every one

Answer (score 0):

Try this PATH setting:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
```

The directory containing `jekyll` is not under `$HOME`.

Comment: I tried this but still not working, may be there is something that makes conflict

Comment: Did you do `hash -r` after updating the path

Comment: If jekyll is installed in that directory, and it has executable permissions, then it should work. You're doing something wrong, but I can't see it from here.

Comment: I think so, I will try to find what makes the problem here