# brew warnings when running brew doctor

Tags: homebrew

Hi when i try to run brew doctor I get a lot of warnings

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    python

Warning: You are using Mac OS X 10.9.
We do not yet provide support for this (unreleased) version.

Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew
If this a surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications.
Stashing returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone
should you later need to do so for some reason.
    cd /usr/local/Library && git stash && git clean -d -f
Error: Homebrew doesn't know what compiler versions ship with your version
of Xcode (5.0.1). Please `brew update` and if that doesn't help, file
an issue with the output of `brew --config`:
  https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues

Thanks!

Warning: You have a curlrc file
If you have trouble downloading packages with Homebrew, then maybe this
is the problem? If the following command doesn't work, then try removing
your curlrc:
  curl http://github.com
```

I tried to fix and search for a solution but didn't solve. 
I think all of theses warnings happened after updating to osx 10.9.

Any one have theses issues

### Edit:

for the brew update I get

```
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Error: Failure while executing: git checkout -q master
```

Comment: Tried `brew update; brew upgrade` ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I tried both and for brew update i get this warning. see my edit.

Comment: Sounds like your homebrew is corrupted. Try to uninstall & re-install. See: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew

Comment: Ok I will reinstall and install it again and hope this will fix it.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I tried to uninstall & re-install and it works just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @ShivanRaptor for suggesting to uninstall & re-install brew and after installing it again everything works just fine.

All warnings gone except this one

```
Warning: You have a curl

rc file
If you have trouble downloading packages with Homebrew, then maybe this
is the problem? If the following command doesn't work, then try removing
your curlrc:
  curl http://github.com
```

But this didn't affect other things because now I fixed the original issues about ruby and ruby gems

Comment: @AhmadAjmi I had same problem with `curlrc`. In home you might have `.curlrc` file. I have renamed it and the warning has gone. Reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/25100088/1745902